# Python doesn't recognize two equal string

Tags: python, string, list

i have a strange problem with String in python. I have two list and I have to found equal name in the two strings. The second list is a readline() from a file opened before.
This is my code:

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen

###VARIABILI###


###FUNZIONI###

def get_mysellers():
   s = open("sellers.txt" , 'r')
   sellers = []
   for line in s:
      sellers.append(line)
   return sellers
   

def get_onlinesellers():
   online_sellers = []
   table_body = soup.findAll('span', {"class": "d-flex has-content-centered mr-1"}) #questa è la tabella contenente la lista dei venditori con annesse informazioni
   i = 0
   for child in table_body:
      #print(child.string)
      online_sellers.append(child.string)
      i = i + 1
   
   return online_sellers
   

def list_of_choosen(selleronline, sellercheck ):
   
   choosen = []
   print(range(len(sellercheck)))
   for i in range(len(selleronline)):
      for j in range(len(sellercheck)):
         if(selleronline[i] == sellercheck[j]):
            choosen.append(sellercheck[j])
   return choosen



###MAIN###

      

page = urlopen("https://www.cardmarket.com/it/YuGiOh/Products/Singles/Chaos-Impact/Draco-Berserker-of-the-Tenyi")
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')

online_sellers = get_onlinesellers()
sellers = get_mysellers()
chosen = list_of_choosen(online_sellers, sellers)
print(chosen)
```

sellers is like this ['L-Air1993\n', 'prova \n', 'CardsellerVienna\n', 'Terrycloth\n']. I think the problem is "\n" but if I print a single element in sellers I obtain the name without "\n"

Thank you very much

Comment: To see if string s has a terminating newline, print(s+"cat"). Does it print on one line, or two?

Comment: @jarmod Just `print(repr(s))`.  That gives a debug representation that shows escape codes for unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2):

When you print 'L-Air1993\n' it will look like it has just the name. The newline just adds a newline at the end but it's hard to see if nothing comes after it.

To remove all the new lines from your list, try this:

```
sellers_no_newlines = [x.strip() for x in sellers]
```

And then compare the online sellers list to sellers_no_newlines. Hopefully that solves your problem.

Comment: You're right, but a more efficient way would be to replace `sellers.append(line)` with `sellers.append(line.rstrip())` in the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method strip in the function get_mysellers to remove the '\n' from the string.

```
def get_mysellers():
   s = open("sellers.txt" , 'r')
   sellers = []
   for line in s:
      Line=line.strip('\n')
      sellers.append(Line)
```